# Auth::attempt not working. Laravel 4

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I got the next code:

```
    public function registrarUsu(){
$datosregistro = array(
    null, 
    "Carlos Delgado",
    "Gonzalez Padron",
    Input::get('username'),
    Hash::make(Input::get('contrasena')),
    );
$consulta = DB::insert('insert into usuarios (id, nombres, apellidos, nick_name, contrasena) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', $datosregistro);
DB::commit($consulta);
}
```

This what it does is; grabs the username and password from a simple login form which I early created, it does what it does, grabs all the data and saves it to the database (The static fields are just for demonstration). The problem is when i try to authenticate the user with the next function:

```
    public function loguearUsu(){
        $datosdeusu = array(
            'nick_name' => Input::get('username'),
            'contrasena' => Input::get('Contrasena'),
                            );

if(Auth::attempt($datosdeusu)){
    return Redirect::to('/');
}}
```

I think that the problem is the password, every time i tried to login it just return false, but if I use a var_dump it shows the username and password just as they are in the database, so what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function loguearUsu(){
    $datosdeusu = array(
        'nick_name' => Input::get('username'),
        'contrasena' => Input::get('Contrasena'),
                        );

   if(Auth::attempt($datosdeusu)){
       return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

your Input::get('contrasena')  on register is not the same as login, recheck

anyway you can use this instead (if the input is two field : username,password)

```
   if(Auth::attempt(Input::all())){

        return Redirect::to('main');

    }
```

Comment: I just did that and gave this sql error:

"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `usuarios` where `_token` = l7f9TJkDFHqbisqPWL2FVo0XPfLpfL0ORKTTGSW8 and `username` = Juanpedroso and `Contrasena` = qqqq limit 1)"

And by looking at that Auth is not hashing my pass to compare it to the one on my database which is: "$2y$10$On7q/pORrwWvfgN1QHoxze7Dl2e6t4KT6n8KY2JkkeFROvuGyUt1O" and is just comparing "qqqq" to the hashed one.

Comment: as of Laravel 4.1 you need to create a column named remember_token on your table. Read more here, http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your user model because you are using a non standard field for the password. Try adding this to your user model. Hope that helps.

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
     return $this->attributes['contrasena'];
}
```